Render webpage across multiple screen in desktop app build
What I would like to do:
I am currently trying to create an windows application that is able to render a website (say https://www.google.com) into multiple screen using .Net MAUI. The app doesn't do anything and does not allow user interaction. The sole purpose of the app is just to render a website, however it has to be able to display the website across all screens available in the computer, which means if there are 3 screens, then that one website will be stretched over 3 screens.
EDIT:
What I mean by that: Say I have 3 physical screens stacked vertically, I would like the first 1/3 part of the webpage showed on the top screen, the middle 1/3 part of the webpage shows on the second screen and the last 1/3 on the bottom screen
What I have done:
as per documentation in .NET, for MainPage.xaml.cs:
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
 {

     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
     {
    base.OnHandlerChanged();
    Window secondWindow = new Window(new MainPage()); // ****
    Application.Current?.OpenWindow(secondWindow);  // ****

     }
}


and for the MainPage.xaml
<WebView 
    Source="https://www.google.com/" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"     
/>

But this didn't work and the website is not rendered. Commenting out the **** part render the website, but it's not stretched across all available screen.
Could you give me a clue of what to do here or point out docs that explain how to render the webpage across multiple screens?

What does the multiple screen mean? Did you want to show the webpage in all the intances of the window?

In addition, the second window in the OnHandlerChanged method will be endless loop.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Say I have 3 screens stacked vertically, I would like the first 1/3 part of the webpage showed on the top screen, the middle 1/3 part of the webpage shows on the second screen and the last 1/3 on the bottom screen

3 physical screens? Or just 3 windows?

@LiyunZhang-MSFT 3 physical screens - if possible only one window stretched out into these 3 physical screens. but if that's impossible, 3 windows (window 1 on top physical screen, window 2 on middle screen and window 3 on bottom screen)

@Vincensiu Windows allows users to rearrange multi-mon desktops arbitrarily - so not all arrangements will work with what you're asking (e.g. a triangular arrangement) - how should your program behave in that situation? (e.g. if you simply have the window fill the entire desktop-workspace's outer bounding-rectangle then the Minimize/Close buttons would be completely inaccessible).

@Dai Thanks for replying. In this situation, I would like it to be somewhat like a kiosk mode. The user does not have the capability to close/ minimise the window, in fact we probably don't even want to allow user interaction. The main purpose of this program is to render a website that can take the whole screen available. The layout is very unlikely to be triangular, most likely to be 3 (or more) screens stacked either horizontally or vertically.

What's the current behaviour of your code if the web site has only a background color with not javascripts or CSS? I think that the main problem here could be the webview because you should set the width or the height to the sum of your 3 screen width or height to tell the website how to calculate the view port. Then you should inject a CSS to zoom the website and display 1/3rd on each screen.
